# OpenVPN - tap interfaces and default gateway

Tags: openvpn

Quick question just to verify i'm not going mental.
If using device mode "tap" and i got a fully function connection in the sense that i can ping from client to server without any issues.

However, i want to force my traffic through the VPN and nothing can leak out, no matter what.
I'm stuck on my head around this but shouldn't this be valid in the `server.ovpn`?

```
mode server
tls-server
...
dev tap
dev-node TAP1

ifconfig 192.168.0.1 255.255.255.0
ifconfig-pool 192.168.0.10 192.168.0.20
route-gateway 192.168.0.1
route 192.168.0.0 255.255.255.0 192.168.0.1

client-to-client
push "route 192.168.0.0 255.255.255.0 192.168.0.1"
push "route-gateway 192.168.0.1"
push "redirect-gateway def1"
```

The `client.ovpn` looks like:

```
client
tls-client
dev tap
dev-node TAP1
...
pull
```

The connection establishes and what not, the output of the clients log is:

```
ROUTE default_gateway=<external IP gateway>
PUSH: Recieved control message: 'PUSH_REPLY,route 192.168.0.0 255.255.255.0 192.168.0.1,route-gateway...
Notified TAP-Win32 driver to set a DHCP IP/netmask of 192.168.0.10/255.255.255.0 on interface ...
Successful ARP Flush
Added routes 139.. 127.. 192...
```

All appears to be fine except that a default gateway just isn't set when checking `ipconfig /all`

The output of the `route print` looks like:

```
Destination        Netmask         Gateway
0.0.0.0            0.0.0.0         <external Gateway>   <-- Wrong?
192.168.0.0        255.255.255.0   On-link
192.168.0.0        255.255.255.0   192.168.0.1
```

The routing table appears to be off?

Comment: Is IP forwarding turned on?  This will be on the server.

Comment: server is running Windows 7, nothing outside of the config has been done. What i'm trying to acomplish is mainly a "dummy gateway" because certain software checks the default gateway parameter in windows for it's operation (mainly for connecting software to a "unknown" server)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
All appears to be fine except that a default gateway just isn't 
set when checking 
...
push "redirect-gateway def1"
```

If you use that option, then you don't set a default gateway.  Instead two routes should be added for `0.0.0.0/1`, and `128.0.0.0/1` to your VPN.

Comment: Ok is it possible to set a default gateway under `ipconfig /all` while still forcing all traffic through the VPN?

Comment: Remove the `def1` option.  Keep in mind that the `def1` option exists because some systems are buggy and will update the default gateway.  For example, in the past some Linux systems would over-write the VPN provided default gateway, if the LAN interface was set to DHCP, and the renew time had occurred.  The `def1` option is generally more reliable, the downside of windows not showing it in `ipconfig /all` is purely cosmetic in my opinion.

Comment: Thank you, the `def1` part was the dark sheep in my problem.
I couldn't agree more that the `ipconfig /all` is purely cosmetic but as mentioned in another comment above, certain software depend on this to work properly and i have 0 control over that software for now even tho it's in house developed :) Thank you!

Answer (score 4):

I realize this is an old question, but I wanted to add that in my experience, if everything works EXCEPT for the setting of a default gateway, running OpenVPN as administrator will solve the problem on Windows 10.

Comment: Yepp this completely slipped my mind and was rather obvious on later years of using VPN, but good addition for anyone ending up here and are new to these kinda things for sure!